# Make a recursive MySQL Update while using IN

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a recursive SELECT query that works as it should, and looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * from Menues WHERE MenuID IN 
    (
        WITH RECURSIVE CTE (MenuID) AS 
        (
          SELECT T.MenuID 
               FROM Menues AS T WHERE T.MenuID in (" + pid + ") 
          UNION ALL SELECT T.MenuID 
               FROM Menues 
               AS T INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.MenuID = T.ParentID
         )
         SELECT MenuID FROM CTE
    );
```

Note that my pid variable looks like "XXX,YYY,ZZZ,..." Where each value is a MenuID
So the select will return recursive branches of rows if they exist (XXX and all children (based on the ParentID=MenuID relationship), YYY and all children etc).

I have a similar SQL UPDATE where I want to set a field - DeletedBy - to the current top MenuID of the branch that the row belongs to. It looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE Menues SET DeletedBy = '" + pid + "' WHERE MenuID IN
    (
        WITH RECURSIVE CTE (MenuID) AS 
        ( 
            SELECT T.MenuID 
                FROM Menues AS T WHERE T.MenuID IN (" + pid + ") 
            UNION ALL SELECT T.MenuID 
                FROM Menues 
                AS T INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.MenuID = T.ParentID
         ) 
         SELECT MenuID FROM CTE
   );
```

This would work fine if pid was a single MenuID, but since I'm using multiple comma separated ids and "IN", The trouble is that DeletedBy will be set to "XXX,YYY,ZZZ". I would like it to be set to either XXX, YYY, or ZZZ, depending on which recursive branch is currently being traversed.
Is this possible to do in a single query?

Of course I could do this by iterating over pid in my code outside of the query, and executing an SQL UPDATE each time, but it would be preferable to do it with a single query.

Comment: mysql has the function fin_in_set, which would be better here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your recursive CTE with additional field `BranchId`.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE `CTE` (`BranchId`, `MenuId`)
AS
(
    SELECT
        `t`.`MenuId`,
        `t`.`MenuId`
    FROM
        `Menues` `t`
    WHERE
        `t`.`MenuId` IN ('XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        `t1`.`BranchId`,
        `t_1`.`MenuId`
    FROM
        `CTE` `t1`
            INNER JOIN `Menues` `t_1` ON `t1`.`MenuId` = `t_1`.`ParentID`
)
UPDATE
    `Menues` `m_1`
        INNER JOIN `CTE` `c_1` ON `m_1`.`MenuId` = `c_1`.`MenuId`
SET
    `m_1`.`DeletedBy` = `c_1`.`BranchId`
```

*query is generated by [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) and has different escaping and aliasing*

Comment: This worked a treat. Big thanks. Now I have to stare at it for 10-60 minutes to figure out the voodoo behind it.